# Codeigniter 3.0 Community Auth - password more than 8 characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've just realized, that there is no matter what characters are over 8 sign in my passwords.

E. g. with password: *Admin1234* also will match *Admin123* and *Admin1235*

In my Community Auth configuration I have set i authentication.php:

```
$config['min_chars_for_password'] = 8;
$config['max_chars_for_password'] = 256;
```

Is this Community Auth bug? Or something misconfigured from my side?

Comment: Can you post the function code?

Comment: @Mr.Web Do you mean - function of Community Auth module? Which function?